# Pulsometer for Android 4.1.2

Tags: running, app

I've seen pulsometers that work only with smartphones with Android 4.3.

Which pulsometers will work with smartphone with an older Android 4.1.2, via Bluetooth?

(Preferably on Samsung S3 mini).

Comment: Why this question has been migrated from sports.stackexchange.com? It seems on topic to me, according to http://meta.sports.stackexchange.com/questions/156/determining-our-scope/332#332: "Equipment purpose/usage: What kind of shoes are suitable for a Novice/Sprint triathlon?".

Answer (score 1):

I did some quick research, and it appears your best bet is the [Zephyr HxM monitor](http://zephyranywhere.com/products/hxm-bluetooth-heart-rate-monitor/). Most of the apps which it lists as compatible should work with your version of android, as should the Bluetooth connection. To be sure about compatibility, I recommend calling or emailing Zephyr before you purchase, as I could not find specific requirements listed anywhere, although some statements implied it should work on android 2.x and later.